# mySQL partitioning multi-file vs. one-file performance?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

When partitioning a large table, I have a choice to set the flag -innodb_file_per_table to TRUE or FALSE.  True will create many files (one per partition) and greatly increase my disk usage, but allows me to spread partitions on different volumes (which I do not plan to do).  FALSE will keep the table as one big file.  Assuming I keep all files on the same logical volume, can I expect any significant query performance difference between the two options?  Or, more generally, are there any issues to consider when making the choice between the two options besides disk usage and management?

Some stats:

- total number of tables: 20 (only a few I am interested in paritioning -
  see my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9743517/ok-to-mix-partitioned-and-unpartitioned-tables-on-same-mysql-server))
- largest tables have 100M records.
- total db size is about 60G.

Comment: before giving any advice could you at least say how big your table is and number of tables in the db? total size of the db?

Answer (score 7):

As you've already stated `-innodb_file_per_table` will decide whether one table will be stored in one file or (if partitioned) in many files.

Here are some pros and con's of each approach (not necessary a complete list).

```
Single file per table                    Multiple files per (partitioned) table
--------------------------------------   --------------------------------------
+ System uses less filehandles           - System uses more filehandles
+ One one fsync per second per table     - Possibly many more fsync calls (bottleneck)
  (less fs overhead (journal etc))         (more fs overhead)
+ Single file uses less space overall    - Much larger disk space usage
- Single file fragments badly            + Less fragmentation 
- Optimize table (et al) takes longer    + You can choose to optimize just one file
- One file = one filesystem              + You can put heavy traffic files on a fast fs
                                           (e.g. on a solid state disk)
- Impossible to reclaim disk space       + possible to emergency-reclaim disk space 
  in a hurry (truncate table takes long)   fast (just delete a file)
- ALTER TABLE can use large % of disk-   + rebuilding with ALTER TABLE will use less
  space for temp tables while rebuilding   temp disk space
```

In general I would **not** recommend multiple files.
If however your workload leads to heavy fragmentation **and** `optimize table` takes too long, using multiple files will make sense.

**Forget about reclaiming space**
Some people make a lot of fuss about the fact that in InnoDB table files always grow and never shrink, leading to wasted space if rows are deleted.
Then they come up with schemes to reclaim that space so as to not run out of free disk space. (`truncate table x`).
This will work much faster with multiple files, however all of this is nonsense, because databases almost always grow and (almost) never shrink, so all that reclaiming of space will waste lots of time (CPU and IO) during with your table will be fully locked (no reads and no writes allowed).
Only to find that your 90% full disk (50% after reclaim) will be 99% full after next months data additions.

**However when using ALTER TABLE beware...**
Consider the following scenario:
- Disk is 60% full.
- database takes up 50%, other files takes up 10%.
If you do an `alter table` on any table, you will run out of disk space if you have all tables in one file.
If you have it in multiple files, you should not have problems (other than caffeine overdose from all that waiting).

Comment: Thank you again.  I did specifically ask about query performance (I am particularly interested in SELECT and UPDATE queries).  Do you have an informed guess or any thoughts on the topic?  I plan to list partition ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-list.html) and I do lots of SELECT and UPDATES on thousands of records per query, but these are always on one or another of the list-segregated partitions.